# D3 nodes overlapping

Tags: javascript, svg, graph, d3.js, collision-detection

I'm using a modified version of the following [example](http://bl.ocks.org/950642) and everything works great so far.

What I am trying to do is to make the nodes bounce from each others and not overlap because I can't see the text and icons of a node if there is another on top of it. Is there a way to make this happen without modifying too much of code that works already? Maybe add something like enabling collision for the nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i its seems that setting the charge to .charge(-300), sets the nodes apart by pushing them away from each others.